# Apple products in movies

Tags: product-placement

Does Apple Computer ever use paid Product Placement in movies or TV shows? While Apple laptops appear frequently in *The Big Bang Theory* I have never seen any of their other products, eg. the Apple Watch, in either The X-Files or any recent Bond movies. Surely "Spooks" like these would be the characters most likely to use such technology?

Comment: I've always assumed that anytime you can clearly tell the brand of a product and/or the characters appear to be *demoing* a feature of the product that the spot is paid. Your link between "spooks" and Apple products seems to be strange IMO.

Comment: Similar question, less specific [here](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31325/are-the-brands-worn-by-the-stars-in-a-movie-part-of-promotions).

Comment: A note about Spooks - Spooks is a BBC production - BBC are state owned and CANNOT advertise. Product placement is advertising therefore it is not allowed on the BBC.

Comment: @PatDobson I thought the OP was using "Spooks" as slang for spies even though the X-Files is FBI if I recall.

Comment: I don't think movies or TV shows are in the habit of giving away publicity they want companies to pay for. Also - final X-files episode - 2002. Apple Watch hits the market - 2015.

Answer (score 9):

I can't find a definitive source from Apple directly, but many mentions that Apple doesn't pay for product placements. [Here's but one](http://bgr.com/2015/03/06/apple-product-placement-movies-2014/):

http://bgr.com/2015/03/06/apple-product-placement-movies-2014/

> Though Apple doesn’t pay for product placement, it certainly has no problem with bestowing large boxes of Apple hardware to production companies in the hopes that iPhones and Macs make it onto some of the biggest TV and movie hits of the year.

The implication that Apple never pays directly for product placement, but seems happy donating props as needed.

Answer (score 4):

Apple really doesn't pay for the product placement. But they have a person to ensure that its products get as much screen time as possible.

From [Network World](https://www.networkworld.com/article/2887929/ios/apples-most-obvious-product-placement-in-movies-and-tv.html),

> While Apple does not pay for product placement in TV shows and movies, that hasn't prevented Apple products from showing up in all kinds of places in the media. As for how it all happens behind the scenes, **Apple marketing chief Phil Schiller once explained that Apple has a point person who works closely with Hollywood to get Apple products as much screen time as possible.**

While other companies have to pay for their product placements, Apple manages to do it free. How? Here it is. From [this Dailytech answer](http://www.dailytech.com/Apple+Gets+Free+Product+Placement+in+TV+Shows+Movies/article24679.htm),

> "Apple won't pay to have their products featured, but they are more than willing to hand out an endless amount of computers, iPads and iPhones," said Gavin Polone, producer of HBO's Curb Your Enthusiasm. "It's kind of a graft situation."

[Other reference](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2012-05-10/apple-the-other-cult-in-hollywood)