# Are there medical equipment product placements in House?

Tags: house, product-placement

I have seen some classic [Apple product placements](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/48984/apple-products-in-movies) but there are also names of some medical equipment manufacturers shown, e.g. on CT Machines.

[image: A Philips MRI Machine in S01E01]
[image: Some closeup footage]

Are there product placements of medical equipment in House?

Comment: If that image is product placement, then it’s not great because I don’t know what make or model bed I’m looking at. And would a medical-equipment company want to spend money advertising via House rather than expos face to face with potential clients who can ask about features etc?

Comment: @Longshanks Agree on the first part, not the second part. Product placement still works even if only targeting a subset of viewers. You're going to get a disproportionately higher ratio of medical personnel watching these shows. I do agree that this isn't product placement, but there's no reason to exclude such a possibility in general.

Comment: I don't have enough for an answer just yet, but it looks like confirmed product placement for a [Ford Explorer](https://www.reddit.com/r/HouseMD/comments/4t12ao/there_was_some_pretty_blatant_product_placement/) but nothing obvious regarding medical equipment. Some people think there was product placement for medical propr (fMRIs / stethascope - http://www.brandspotters.com/episodes.aspx?id=624) but it could just be unintentional because of how the props/set dressing was sourced

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Medical equipment is *probably* more likely donated, brought, or hired as needed

I say probably because I haven't yet found a source specifically for *House*.

But, a similar show in the UK called *Casualty*, which is a long-running medical drama, also uses a range of medical equipment. A [BBC blog](https://www.bbc.co.uk/blogs/aboutthebbc/entries/7516b055-1caa-426d-a721-c0f97d3c7fdd) describes how:

> Much of the medical equipment and props used in the show are donated from former hospitals. Other items have to be bought in, and others are made on site for specific episodes.

It's likely that once the sets were constructed for *House*, which would be kept until production ended, specific medical equipment needed for an episode was hired on an episode-by-episode basis.

I know from experience on a short film that you can hire medical props for a day or longer quite easily. For example, in the UK, you can hire an MRI from https://www.medicalhire.co.uk/:

[image: MRI for hire]

And in the US you could hire your very own ultrasound machine from https://medicalmovieprops.com/inventory:

[image: Ultrasound for hire]