# Do stars of original series get royalties for reboots or remakes?

Tags: casting, film-industry, remake, copyright, reboot

While this may be a bit subjective, the recent remake of ***Roots***, produced by the original star, Levar Burton, got me to think.

Is it common, or even heard of, for an actor or star to get royalties for their character once it has been rebooted? Does an actor get some sort of claim on a role past their original performance? If so, what's the first instance of this?

Comment: Unless they have the rights to the character, why would they?

Comment: @walt very good foresight in contract negotiations? Some obscure copyright law or court ruling? Hence the question. If a character comes to prominence because of a specific actors interpretation, why shouldn't they have some right to the character?

Answer (score 2):

No, actors do not get royalties from reboots.  The characters are the property of the writer(s), and only they are capable of getting royalties from reboots.

Edit:

Not sure who flagged this, but they're more than welcome to read [this overly complex legalese](http://www.ivanhoffman.com/characters.html) on the subject.

Comment: Downvoter: Read [this](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/31313/are-movie-stars-typically-forbidden-from-appearing-in-future-commercials-resembl?rq=1).  You should conclude (correctly) that characters are not owned by the actors, and thus are not eligible to get royalties from one.

Comment: I think maybe adding some of those court cases described may be helpful to flesh out your answer.